# javascript code and zindex

Tags: javascript, html, z-index

I am having problems with getting the z-index to change using javascript can any one help me on where I am going wrong,

what I am trying to do is have a box appear on top on another box once a button is clicked but it does not seem to work.

```
function toggleupload(){
            var but = document.getElementById('picbutton').innerHTML;
            if (but == "Change Picture"){
                            document.getElementById('picbutton').innerHTML = "Hide upload box";
                            document.getElementById('uploadbox').style.zIndex = 2;
                            document.getElementById('profilebasic').style.zIndex = 1;
            }
            if (but == "Hide upload box"){
                            document.getElementById('picbutton').innerHTML = "Change Picture";
                            document.getElementById('uploadbox').style.zIndex = 1;
                            document.getElementById('profilebasic').style.zIndex = 2;
            }

}




#profilebasic{
            width:300px;
            height:300px;
            z-index:2;
            background-color:#0F0;

}
#uploadbox {
            position:absolute;
            top:0px;
            left:0px;
            width:300px;
            height:300px;
            z-index:1;
            background-color:#F00;

}
#uploadbo{
            text-align:center;
            width:300px;
            height:300px;
            z-index:3;

}




<div id="uploadbo">
<div id="profilebasic">
</div>
<div id="uploadbox">
</div>
<button  onclick="toggleupload();" id="picbutton">Change Picture</button>
            </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean "it does not seem to work"? Is anything happening at all? Are you seeing any error messages in your console?

Comment: Yes the name changes but nothing else and I got no error going to try the fix that has been posted

Comment: you should be using an else and not another if statement!

Comment: thank I was thinking that but was unsure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `z-index` property [only works on positioned elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Understanding_z-index/Adding_z-index), so you need to explicitly set the position on `profilebasic` like:

```
#profilebasic {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    z-index:2;
    background-color:#0F0;
    position:absolute;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rbs8d/1/)**

(note that I also had to set some CSS on your button otherwise it would have ended up under your positioned divs.)

Comment: Why `absolute` and not `relative`?

Comment: @Ian - relative positioning would work fine too. I said it just has to be positioned, not absolutely positioned. I merely used the same positioning the OP used on his other div.

Comment: No problem, I just wanted to make sure. I just try to stay away from absolute unless I need to be absolutely positioned

Answer (score 0):

Since `uploadbox` already starts out in front I assume you want to swap these.

Based on z-index rules, an absolutely positioned div will still appear in front of a non-absolutely positioned div unless its z-index value is negative.

That is, use a negative z-index for the box you want to be behind.

http://jsfiddle.net/X54gr/